# Stretched width for rotated UILabel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Sorry i'm really can't figure out how is native iOS design works (i'm usually do Xamarin Forms design).
I have `UIStackView`

`UIStackView stackView = new UIStackView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));`

then i create `UILabel`, set `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` because i need auto adjusted font size

after that i apply some rotation to it `targetLabel.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(new nfloat(Math.PI * 270 / 180.0));` because i need to make vertical text.

and then i add this label to the stack. Of course i have some other setups too but i think they are doesn't matter.

my final step is to set new `Frame` for `UILabel` with fixed width. I tried set width by getting stack's height, i tried even set it to constant, but it doesn't work. Width of the label always looks like auto.

this is what i want:

[image]

but in fact, the target label is very small.

Full code here: (Note this is TodayExtension)

```
[Register("CodeBasedViewController")]
    public class CodeBasedViewController : SLComposeServiceViewController, INCWidgetProviding
    {
        UIImage image;
        private UILabel otherLabel;
        private UILabel targetLabel;

        public CodeBasedViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

                UIStackView stackView = new UIStackView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
                View.AddSubview(stackView);
                stackView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal;
                image = new UIImage("picture.png");
                UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(image)
                {
                    ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                };
                otherLabel = new UILabel
                {
                    TextColor = UIColor.White,
                    Text = "someTextA",
                    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(40)
                };
                targetLabel = new UILabel
                {
                    TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                    Text ="4",
                    TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left,
                    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(30),
        AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true,
                    Lines = 1
                };
                targetLabel.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(new nfloat(Math.PI * 270 / 180.0));
                stackView.AddArrangedSubview(imageView);
                stackView.AddArrangedSubview(otherLabel);
                stackView.AddArrangedSubview(targetLabel);
                stackView.Frame = new CGRect(View.Frame.Width / 2, 0,
                    otherLabel .IntrinsicContentSize.Width +
                    targetLabel.IntrinsicContentSize.Width +
                    View.Frame.Height
                    , View.Frame.Height);
                stackView.Center = View.Center;

        targetLabel.Frame = new CGRect(targetLabel.Frame.X, targetLabel.Frame.Y, 150, 150); //test constants

        }

        public void WidgetPerformUpdate(Action<NCUpdateResult> completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, set the property `Distribution` of StackView

```
stackView.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill;
```

And don't forget to set the Font of label at the same time

```
targetLabel.Frame = new CGRect(targetLabel.Frame.X, targetLabel.Frame.Y, 150, 150);
targetLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(80);
```

Following is the full code , I set the frame just for test and you can set the frame as you want(if you want to set the equals the size of screen , you should set the frame of label and imageView at same time).

```
UIStackView stackView = new UIStackView(new CGRect(100,200,300,150));
View.AddSubview(stackView);
stackView.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill;
stackView.Spacing = 10;
stackView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
stackView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal;

UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView()
{
  ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit,
  BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red           
};

otherLabel = new UILabel
{
  TextColor = UIColor.Black,
  Text = "someTextA",
  Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(40)
};

targetLabel = new UILabel
{
  TextColor = UIColor.Black,
  Text = "4",
  TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left,
  Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(100),
  AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true,
  Lines = 0
};

targetLabel.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(new nfloat(Math.PI * 270 / 180.0));
stackView.AddArrangedSubview(imageView);
stackView.AddArrangedSubview(otherLabel);
stackView.AddArrangedSubview(targetLabel);

stackView.Center = View.Center;

targetLabel.Frame = new CGRect(targetLabel.Frame.X, targetLabel.Frame.Y, 150, 150);
```

[image]

Comment: `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` still doesn't work. Now `targetLabel` just always big

Comment: What's the means of  always big ?

Comment: Provide the screen shot on your device .

Comment: I mean the font is always big, even with longer text: https://yadi.sk/i/ZKfq-47duJqh8A

Comment: You have to set the font large enough when you init the label `Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(100),`  And remove the line `targetLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(80);`

Comment: this is my code now: https://yadi.sk/i/wDxieofqXXjupA
and result is the same: too big text in `targetLabel`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199737/discussion-between-sudalv-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: Set `Lines=0,` .You code now works fine on my side .